# How to parse jsonarray convert to string using volley lib in android

Tags: android, authentication

has i am create sample login form using Volley lib in android but i have error for value your of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

sample code

```
      JsonArrayRequest stringRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(LOGIN_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
    {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response)
                {

                    try {
                        // Parsing json array response
                        // loop through each json object
                        jsonResponse = "";
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++)
                        {

                            JSONObject person = (JSONObject)response.get(i);
                            String uerid = person.getString("user_id");
                            String un = person.getString("user_name");
                            String unemail = person.getString("user_email");
                            String unpwd =person.getString("user_password");
                            String unmbl =person.getString("user_mobileno");




                            jsonResponse += "user id " + uerid + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "user name: " + un + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "" + unemail + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "" + unpwd + "\n\n";
                            jsonResponse += "" + unmbl + "\n\n";


                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+jsonResponse,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d("Error new: " + error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(KEY_USERNAME,username);
            map.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
            return map;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

error :value your of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

how to parse this response jsonarray to string ? give me solution

Comment: Probably not getting valid JSON String from Server use any HTTP tool and show with question what String getting in response from Server

Comment: You are trying to convert a value which is not a JSONArray.

Comment: Can you post your error log?

Comment: can you post your json format which is coming from server?